# Vb conceptual understanding of creating objects within a class

Tags: vb.net

I was wondering if you could help me understand how to create a Card object (with a value and suit) and use 52 of those cards to make an object called deck.

I have created my card class how do I initialize every card inside the deck class?  Should I do it one by one?  How do I link all those cards to one deck.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it happen I did read your previous question earlier today.

First, create a suit enum.

```
Public Enum Suit As Integer
    Hearts = 1
    Diamonds = 2
    Clovers = 3
    Spades = 4
End Enum
```

Then create the card class. Notice that the properties are read only as a card never changes its value. (Maybe not true if you're a magician)

```
Public Class Card

    Public Sub New(suit As Suit, value As Integer)
        Me.m_suit = suit
        Me.m_value = value
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Suit() As Suit
        Get
            Return Me.m_suit
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Value() As Integer
        Get
            Return Me.m_value
        End Get
    End Property

    Private m_suit As Suit
    Private m_value As Integer

End Class
```

Finally, create the deck class and populate 52 cards.

```
Public Class Deck

    Public Sub New()
        Dim cards = New Card(52 - 1) {}
        Dim num As Integer = 0
        For s As Integer = 1 To 4
            For v As Integer = 1 To 13
                cards(num) = New Card(CType(s, Suit), v)
                num += 1
            Next
        Next
        Me.m_cards = New Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection(Of Card)(cards)
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Cards() As Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection(Of Card)
        Get
            Return Me.m_cards
        End Get
    End Property

    Private ReadOnly m_cards As Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection(Of Card)

End Class
```

Comment: Question, I am very new to VB, where do you create your enum portion is it within the class or within the main program?

Comment: @user3363744 For each item (an enum, a class, .. or whatsoever) just right-click the project in the solutions pane , go to `Add` > `New`, select `Class` and type the item name. Eg. `Suit.vb`. Then remove the  code created by VS and replace it with `Public Enum Suit As Integer` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You need two Enumerations and two Classes:

- Enumerations

  1. CardFaceValue - with values ranging from Ace-10 (inclusive), Jack, Queen, King.
  2. CardFaceType - with values Hearts, Spades, Clubs, Diamonds
- Classes

  1. Deck - Has one property to contain the collection of all cards

     1. Cards - of Type Array of Cards, sized 52.
  2. Card - Has two properties

     1. CardFaceValue
     2. CardFaceType

In the constructor of the Deck class run a loop within a loop. The outer loop will run for 4 times for each of the CardFaceType enumeration, and the inner loop will run for 13 times for cards 1-10, J, Q, K.

With these loops iterate through the enumeration values and add cards to your Deck.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a quick draft of what I envision

You'll need the card class first.

```
Public Class Card

    Private cSuit As String
    Private cValue As Integer

    Public Property suit() As String
        Get
            Return cSuit
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            cSuit = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property value() As Integer
        Get
            Return cValue
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            value = cValue
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New(ByVal TheSuit As String, ByVal TheValue As Integer)

        cSuit = TheSuit
        cValue = TheValue

    End Sub
```

Then you can make a new object for each card and add it to the deck collection.

```
Dim Deck As New List(Of Card)
        Dim Suit As String = "Spade"
        Dim Value As Integer = 11

        Dim AceOfSpades As New Card(Suit, Value)

        Deck.Add(AceOfSpades)
```

Comment: But then the Deck might be incomplete, have duplicates and/or over 52 cards.

Comment: What if you want an incomplete deck or more than one deck of cards to increase the odds? Many games play with more than one deck. I think a basic adaptable solution for a vague question is fair. Even further, what if he isn't playing with a standard deck. What if its Yugio or Pokemon or something.

Comment: Why would the OP specifically ask for a Deck class if he just wanted a collection? Also he specifically asked for the card to be linked to the deck. In your code the card could very well be in multiple decks.

Comment: If you have one collection, that's only one deck.

Comment: This was the approach I was taking.  Question, wouldnt you also need to add a method .Add?

Comment: Negative, the .Add method is already included in the List(of T) class        http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx and so are many other methods for finding stored objects and manipulating them.